# Counting slashes

Tags: c#, string

```
int nextSymbol = i + 1;
char typeOfQuotes = line[i];    

private static void ParseComplexField(string line, StringBuilder tokenBuilder, ref int i, char typeOfQuotes)
        {
            int slashCount = 0;
            for (; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                if (line[i] == '\\')
                {
                    slashCount++;
                    if (line[i - 1] == '\\' && slashCount % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        tokenBuilder.Append("\\");
                        slashCount = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (line[i] == typeOfQuotes)
                {
                    if (line[i - 1] == '\\' && slashCount % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        tokenBuilder.Append(typeOfQuotes);
                        slashCount = 0;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                else
                {
                    tokenBuilder.Append(line[i]);
                    slashCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I get rid of the slash counting or replace it with something? Reading my code, it seems that many slashes in a row mean something, although in reality this is not the case.

It should work like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us a possible input, current output and desired output?

Comment: What is the purpose of this code, in general? It seems like it does something simple, but does it in a overly complex way.

Comment: @Marco I added an image

Comment: Either I didn't have enough coffee today, or the image doesn't help at all. What are the rules for the splitting?

Comment: You are talking about your code like someone else was the author: _"Reading my code, it seems that many slashes in a row mean something"_ You don't know the reason for the code that you have written?

Comment: Why don't you use regular expressions to split the content?

Comment: @Carles Exactly my first thought, but OP doesn't seem to understand the splitting rules behind this logic either.

Comment: @Asunez RegEx could be complex but saves a lot of time and issues. Have a look to http://regex101.com/

Comment: @Carles You misunderstood me. I know what regexes are and how complex they can be. I'm just saying that the author of the question doesn't seem to understand what the code he presented does, and writing Regex without this knowledge is going to be hard for him.

Comment: It looks like this code is designed to split up a long string into fields, where each field is surrounded with quotes - but quotes can be escaped with a slash, and slashes can also be escaped with a slash. I don't think it needs re-writing, it just needs commenting to explain what it does.